# dovecot SSL Handshake problems

Tags: ssl, openssl, centos, dovecot

I try to enable SSL for dovecot. So I generate/installed the certificates with openssl. But when I try to test the conncection the client reports errors. Maybe somebody could help me resp. point me into the right direction?

**Command Line Input:** openssl s_client -connect localhost:pop3s

**Result/Error:**

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
47751153546184:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake  failure:s23_lib.c:177:
```

**Dovecot version:** 2.0.9

**Openssl version:** 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

**Dovecot config for SSL:**

```
ssl = yes
ssl_cert = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
```

**OpenSSL comand line how the certs has been generated**:

openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private/dovecot.pem -out certs/dovecot.pem -days 365

Any hints are welcome. Thanks oyu in advance.

regards
Mark

Comment: The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) might be of interest to you. It will explain what's on-topic and what's off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

For a more detailed error report that may help you debug the problem, try

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:pop3s -debug
```